# php Laravel Ajax couldn't load muliple object data in View

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Here the scenario is, 
I want to show some students data where user can select a student username and student related data will be loaded in view page.
The problem is students data get loaded but it's showing only last array's data.
Eg. A student have two courses with grade. While I select that student only last course he selected and related data shown not with others.

While I checked in console, I can see all the results but not in my view page.

How do I solve the problem?

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('/viewResultPage',[
    'uses'=>'ResultController@viewResultPage',
    'as'=>'viewResultPage'
    ]);
```

Here is the controller:

```
 public function ajax_student_result(Request $request)
    {
            $std_id= $request->input(['std_id']);
         $student = DB::table('results')->join('grades','results.grade_id', '=','grades.id')
           ->join('courses', 'results.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
           ->join('students', 'results.student_id', '=', 'students.id')
           ->join('departments','students.department_id','=','departments.id')
           ->where('students.id', $std_id)                      
           ->selectRaw('students.name,students.email,departments.name as d_name,
             courses.name as c_name,courses.code as c_code,grades.grade')
           ->get();

            return \Response::json($student); 
    }
```

And here is the view page with Ajax :

```
<div class="container" >
            <h3> View Result </h3>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Student Reg No.</label>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" required id="student" name="student_id" >
            <option>Select a Student</option>
            @foreach($student as $row)
            <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->registraion_number}}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>   

       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"  >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"  >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Department</label>
          <input type="text" name="department" id="department" class="form-control"  >
        </div>

        <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered"  id="example">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Serial No</td>
            <td>Course Code</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Grade</td>                      
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $i=1; ?>       
           @foreach ($student as $row)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$i}}</td>
            <td id="code"></td>
            <td id="course_name"></td>
            <td id="grade"></td>         
          </tr>
           <?php $i++; ?>             
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>          
        </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
         $('#student').on('change',function(e){       

           var std_id = $('#student option:selected').attr('value');

          $.ajaxSetup({
                      headers: {
                          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                      });

                   $.ajax({ 
                      type: "POST", 
                      url : "{{url('ajax-student-result')}}",
                      data:{std_id:std_id},
                    success : function(data) {                  
                  $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj){
                    $('#name').val(subcatObj.name); 
                    $('#email').val(subcatObj.email); 
                    $('#department').val(subcatObj.d_name);

                    $('#code').html(subcatObj.c_code);
                    $('#course_name').html(subcatObj.c_name);
                    $('#grade').html(subcatObj.grade);

                    });
                   } 

                  });

       });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies within this code:

```
$.each(data,function(index,subcatObj){
    $('#name').val(subcatObj.name); 
    $('#email').val(subcatObj.email); 
    $('#department').val(subcatObj.d_name);

    $('#code').html(subcatObj.c_code);
    $('#course_name').html(subcatObj.c_name);
    $('#grade').html(subcatObj.grade);

});
```

You get an array of data, but since you are using the jquery.each method, you are only overwriting the values in the table row (since there is only one row).

If you want to show all the array data, you should append new rows in the table, for example:

```
success : function(data) {
    // First empty table   
    $("#example").empty();

    // Populate table with student info and courses
    $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj) {
        $('#example tbody').after('<tr><td>'+subcatObj.name+'</td></tr>'+ ... +'<tr><td>'+index+'</td><td id="code">'+subcatObj.c_code+'</td> ... </tr>');
    });
}
```

This will create new rows in table for each key in the array

Edit: You also need to empty the table when selecting a new student.
This can be achieved with

```
 $("#example").empty();
```

Thats why I added the line in the success function of the ajax callback

Comment: The problem with your above code is it doesn't delete the previous value means while I select another student it's added with the existed value.

Comment: Updated answer, see Edit in the answer